# window.load event not getting fired when I open a link in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening a link in new tab using **Ctrl+click.** Simultaneously I am opening 6 to 7 tabs. On few pages I am getting it and on some its not working.

**Browser - Chromium ,Version 53.0.2785.143 Built on Ubuntu , running on LinuxMint 17.3 (64-bit)**

This is the my code.

```
$(window).load(function () {
      alert('here');
});
```

What could be the possible issue ?

I have even tried this but no luck.

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){
   if(document.readyState == "complete"){
      console.log(document.readyState);
   }
});
```

Basically I want to fire an event when whole page is completely loaded.

Comment: Try $(document).ready(function () { alert('here'); });

Comment: `It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser` https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: I need to fire an event when whole page is loaded , so document.ready is not a solution in my case.

Comment: @JonasW. : so what is the solution or alternative way to achieve this.

Comment: `document.readyState` OR you can check http://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded for more info

Comment: @MilanChheda : Even that is not working in my case.

Comment: Put that in `SetInterval()` and check every second if `document.readyState == 'complete'`

Comment: @MilanChheda : I don' think that is the solution here. The problem is something else . Sometimes event is not getting bind to the document.

Comment: Have you tryed `$(window).on("load",function(){alert("Here");})` ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette : Yes I have tried that even but no luck.